# Why Docker mounts only specific files in volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.6
BuildVersion:   17G65

$ docker -v
Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825
```

I have some docker-compose file that actually has this string of line:

```
volumes:
    - .:/sql
```

And In "." directory I have plenty of directories and files:

```
$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r--   1 michael  staff   161 Nov  9 13:35 README.ms
drwxr-xr-x  12 michael  staff   384 Nov  9 13:35 backend
-rwxr-xr-x   1 michael  staff  1438 Nov  9 13:35 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x  12 michael  staff   384 Nov 10 13:28 ops
drwxr-xr-x   5 michael  staff   160 Nov  9 13:35 requirements
-rw-r--r--   1 michael  staff    38 Nov  9 13:35 requirements.txt
```

But when I start this container and go inside, all I see there:

```
# ls -1 /sql
docker-compose.yml
ops
```

Pay attention: file docker-compose.yml is even not from this directory. It is from ops/

Who has an idea of the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the reason.

No matter where you start docker-compose from, it takes "." as a location of docker-compose.yml file. Thus, all you expect to see inside container have to be located within the very same directory where docker-compose.yml resides at.